# Windows 10 won't boot from usb. Windows logo displays and spinning circle

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb

I have serious problem with PC. I can't boot even from USB Stick. I created it on different machine with the help of: `Microsoft Media Creation Tool`.

I disabled `Secure boot` and `Fast boot` in bios and selected this usb to start in boot menu (`Asus Motherboard`). The Leagcy and UEFI (hybrid) mode is enabled.

It is booting from usb but after windows logo appears and spinning circle starts and after 2-3 seconds the spinning circle stops spinning and the screen freezes with windows logo and circle (not spinning). No blues screens, no error messages, no black screen, no feedback at all.

I've checked this usb stick on different PC and boots without any problem. I've also checked many different usb ports in this problematic PC. Nothing helps.

**UPDATE:**
I tried to disable CSM mode (aka Legacy Mode) so the only UEFI mode is enabled. Rebooted several times (the same windows logo, sometimes spinning circle is showing sometimes not, if it is showing then after 2-3 seconds it stops spinning) and one time I received Blue Screen with such message:
`Thread Exception Not Handled`.

Comment: You need to disable Legacy Mode.  You want to boot the device in UEFI mode.  Your current issue is your trying to boot into Legacy mode

Comment: I disabled CSM aka Legacy Mode. Now I'm receiving Blue Screen with the message: Thread Exception Not Handled during booting from usb. This Blue Screen is showing sometimes but mainly it is freezing with not spinning circle and windows logo.

Comment: Is it a hardware issue? Try booting from a Linux distro on USB... if that fails, then it may be hardware at fault.

Comment: try to re-do the windows installation on the usb,  could just be a faulty installation

Comment: I tried this usb on 2 different machines and it works perfectly.